# Debug .NET assembly with dnSpy

Tags: c#, .net, reverse-engineering

I know it might be a bit concrete question given the fact that I am asking for one specific tool (dnSpy), but I hope that there might be some general mistake I am doing.

So I have this tool dnSpy which is basically .net reverse engineering tool there is the source code for anyone who is interested - https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy

I am trying to debug assembly because our company is using microservices architecture and many of the source code is coming from nugets(.dlls) and occasionally there is problem with these microservices , but I don't want to stay aside and wait for the architecture unit to fix it , but rather find the problem myself for this reason I want to debug some of the assemblies referenced by our website application.

What I am doing is I am attaching to website process id and then put breakpoints in dnSpy at the methods our website is calling in certain dll. But once our website calls the dll dnSpy is not doing anything and now I am stuck.

I know there is forum in github , but I really hope that someone is using dnSpy and can help me, before guys at github reply.